# Flatlist is inverted and I have no idea why

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

So, my Flatlist is inverted by I did not make it like that.

How do I know that is is inverted: **onEndReached** is called when I pull the list (like I was pulling to refresh). But when I add 'inverted' inside Flatlist, it does the expected behavior (called when I get to the bottom of it).

Flatlist code:

```
<FlatList
    data={testing}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <ListItem
            data={item}
            onPress={() => handlePressItem(item)} />
    )}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <ListDivider isCentered />}
    style={styles.list}
    ListFooterComponent={renderFooter()}
    onEndReached={() => { console.log('reached') }}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
/>
```

Here's the response from my API call (inside 'testing' variable):

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Name 1",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Name 2",
    },...
```

I have already tried to change the api call to order by ID DESC, but it does not solved the problem.

Any ideas of what is happening?

Comment: May I know how many rows are being rendered in the flatlist as if there are not many rows then the method onEndReached invoke as you are doing pull to refresh which will update the state and the flatlist will re-render again after the pull to refresh.

Comment: @JigneshMayani I'm rendering exactly the number of rows that the api returns. My api returns 10 rows and a 'next page' field. So I'm rendering 10 rows and expected to call the next page 'onEndReached'

Comment: Does the 10 rows cover up the screen of some space left on screen ?

Comment: Space left. Is it because of the space? I can't believe it

Comment: I think so as your list reached at the end so the endReached should be called

Comment: @JigneshMayani it solved the problem. Thank you so much!!